# Play multiple sounds in uiwebview

Tags: javascript, html, uiwebview, media, html5-audio

After searching this database  for the last few hours I found that safari (and uiwebview) treat the audio tag as a singleton and will therefor only create one audio player each time.

My Question: Is there a ready made objectiveC (phonegap-like) tool that I can use to call from JS to create multiple concurrent audio players or do I need to dive into objective C programming to create the native code and the bridge that will allow me to activate the players from JS?

Background:
I am working on a game and need to play multiple sounds concurrently (e.g. bg music and button click). I am writing the game in javascript for cross platform purposes (also for ready made website game demos), the ios version is packed as an app using phonegap.

I am using the following code to preload my audio files:

```
var elem = document.createElement('audio');
elem.addEventListener("loadeddata", function() {                  
    handler.audioLoaded(name);
    ready = true;
}, true);
elem.setAttribute('src', src);
elem.load();
```

this code is called in a loop for each audio resource - works fine in chrome on desktop but when run on ipad only the first resource that get loaded is available - next resources dont get loaded and are not played when `elem.play()` is called.

Any advice will be highly appreciated.

============================================================================

Update: turns out phonegap Media object does the job well and plays multiple audio files at once.